# PHAsset with Optimize IPhone Storage

Tags: ios, icloud, phasset

When I use the device Optimize IPhone Storage (Settings -> iCloud -> Photos) some photos will be sent to iCloud. How do I know that PHAsset is in iCloud before retrieve the image?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Apple doesn't actually let you know whether the image/video is on the device. You just have to make the request and it will either succeed or fail. If it failed then it's probably not on the device.